# Prevent Word from Reformatting my HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, ms-word

I have an HTML page that needs to open in word. I created the document in word and saved the document as an HTML document. So word spits out all its nasty HTML syntax. This is the opened through internet explorer which will display the word document within the browser.

When I view the page word modifies some of the tags. More specifically it adds a Width and Height tag and ignores the width and height within the style tag. If I try setting the Width and Height tags it overrides with new values. I have tested on different environments and get different results as word makes decision how to handle.

A bit of background this img starts off as this, and is rendered via data rendering syntax.

```
<asp:Image id="as" runat="server" Src"<%# ImgSource %>" style="width:178px;height:130px" />
```

It ends up like this in word

```
<img width=32
          height=32 id=barCodeImage
          src="http://myurl/BarcodeImages/1136574_129180418198008169.png"
          style='border-bottom-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;border-right-width:0px;
          border-top-width:0px;height:130px;width:178px'>
```

I want to stop word from reformatting the HTML.

Comment: Can you explain why you need word to open the HTML?

Comment: I second that. If you want Word to stop messing with your code, I'd stop using Word. You don't use a chainsaw to cut your hair (could work, but is highly inappropriate), do you? ;)

Comment: Its got to do with printing a document instead of an HTML document. We are strongly considering going with something else etc PDF or reporting services ... we have kinda pushed this solution to its limits. The question still remains though.

Comment: I understand you are not happy with the solution, as am I. The question still remains though, is it possible to prevent word from modifying the tags.

Comment: Go with what you are already thinking of doing. Move to using PDF or something else.

Comment: @Blair McMillan decided to go with reporting services. So the issue still exists. Would be nice to know a way to get word to stop doing this!

Answer (score 0):

Try Saving the page with the format "Webpage(Filtered)" in word.... I was compiling a help file and using the filtered save most of the words meta tags removed.....